# How to get selected checkbox index in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, checkbox, foreach

I have a checkbox as follows,

```
<tr>
  <td>
     <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="feegroupid[]" class="fee_checkbox" value="<?php echo $fee_value->fee_groups_feetype_id ?>">
  </td>

   <td> 
      <input type="text" name="actual_pay[]" class="form-control modal_amount actual_pay" id="amount" value="<?php echo $feetype_balance; ?>">
   </td>
   </tr>
```

And my PHP function if the checkbox row is selected,

```
  foreach($_POST['feegroupid'] as $index => $selected) {

     echo $index; 

     $actualPayment = $_POST['actual_pay'][$index];      

    }
```

I have two rows with checkbox,
Here the `echo $index` is displaying only the first row index `0` if i select the second row (whose index is 1).
But both is selected (ie.checked), it is showing both index as `0,1` respectively.. But when we uncheck one checkbox(say first row with index `0` is unchecked), it is showing the `0` only but checked index is `1`.

I am in the need to get the value of another input box with name `actual_pay[]` based on the checked box index..

How to get the respective checked box index instead of the first row index while changing checkbox?

Attached image has a button click to pay which should send the checked box index (ie, second box is checked and its index is `1`).

[image]

Comment: Checkboxes are only sent to the PHP from the browser IF they are Checked

Comment: How can i get the index of that checked box? Because i need to get a value of another class based on the checked box index.

Comment: Look at the value and not the index

Comment: use `$selected` not the `$index`

Comment: It is showing error ```undefined offset```..

Comment: Can you show how do you display it ?

Comment: I have attached an image in my question.

Comment: If i give ```$actualPayment = $_POST['actual_pay'][$selected];
          echo $actualPayment;```  It is showing the error, ```Undefined offset: 26``` where 26 is the checked box value.

Comment: `$selected` in this case would contain 1,0 (depending on checked) not the index. @ManiRaj you have to understand that if a checkbox is *not* checked it will not post! Checkboxes area pidas in that respect because they only post when they are set! e.g. val = 1.

Comment: We can leverage one thing... but I must know, is `fee_groups_feetype_id` unique to one item?

Comment: @Alex, Yes the ```fee_groups_feetype_id``` is unique..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="feegroupid[]" class="fee_checkbox" value="<?php echo $fee_value->fee_groups_feetype_id; ?>">
    </td>
    <td> 
        <input type="text" name="ap_<?php echo $fee_value->fee_groups_feetype_id; ?>" class="form-control modal_amount actual_pay" id="amount" value="<?php echo $feetype_balance; ?>">
    </td>
</tr>
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['feegroupid'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['feegroupid'] as $k => $v) {
        if (isset($_POST['ap_' . $v])) {
            echo $_POST['ap_' . $v]; //$actualPayment
        } else {
            echo 'Not found for item: ap_' . $v;
        }
    }
}
```